# Value in Dictionary is not always replaced

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to replace values in a `dictionary` with new values. However, sometimes they get replaced and sometimes not...

The file can be downloaded here: https://easyupload.io/imkzb9

```
with open('zip_codes_germany.json') as originalFile:
    zipCodes = json.load(originalFile)
    for index, feature in enumerate(zipCodes):
        if feature['place'] == 'Berlin':
            zipCode = feature['zipcode']
            newQuery = f"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?postalcode={zipCode}&country=Germany&format=json"
            with urllib.request.urlopen(newQuery) as response:
                jsonData = json.loads(response.read())
                try:
                    feature['community'] = jsonData[0]['display_name']
                    zipCodes[index] = feature
                except IndexError:
                    print(zipCode) # only done once
            time.sleep(2)
    with open('zip_codes_germany_2.0.json', 'w') as newFile:
        newFile.write(json.dumps(zipCodes))
```

Now, when searching for the `zipcode=10997`, the original value `Berlin, Stadt` for the key `community` is still there.
Searching for the `zipcode=10318`, the value that the OSM API returns in `display_name` replaced the old `community` value. Why is that?

Comment: share the dict (or a subset of it), share the code that does the 'replace' and explain what is wrong with the output

Comment: @balderman--OP provides a link to the file containing the json i.e. https://easyupload.io/imkzb9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is some of the dictionaries don't meet your condition for updating.

Meaning, you are performing updates on a list of dictionaries.  The update is only performed when the value for the 'place' key of the dictionary is 'Berlin', i.e.:

```
if feature['place'] == 'Berlin':
```

The dictionary with zipcode 10318 is:

```
{
    "country_code": "DE",
    "zipcode": "10318",
    "place": "Berlin",
    "state": "Berlin",
    "state_code": "BE",
    "province": "",
    "province_code": "00",
    "community": "Berlin, Stadt",
    "community_code": "11000",
    "latitude": "52.4835",
    "longitude": "13.5287"
},
```

This dictionary value for key "place' is "Berlin" so it meets the condtion and gets updated.

The dictionary with zipcode 10997 is:

```
{
    "country_code": "DE",
    "zipcode": "10997",
    "place": "Berlin Kreuzberg",
    "state": "Berlin",
    "state_code": "BE",
    "province": "",
    "province_code": "00",
    "community": "Berlin, Stadt",
    "community_code": "11000",
    "latitude": "52.5009",
    "longitude": "13.4356"
},
```

This value for the key 'place' is "Berlin Kreuzberg" (i.e. not "Berlin").  Since this does not match the condition it is not updated.